# How to fail a script assertion in SoapUI?

Tags: groovy, http-headers, soapui, assertions

I'm trying to let a script assertion fail, when a variable has another value than defined. My goal: Mark the TestStep as red, if the TestStep will fail.  Please note that I am using a script assertion for a TestStep - not a separate Groovy-Script TestStep.
My script looks like this:

```
httpResponseHeader = messageExchange.responseHeaders
contentType = httpResponseHeader["Content-Type"]
log.info("Content-Type: " + contentType)

if (contentType != "[image/jpeg]"){
    log.info("ERROR! Response is not an image.")
    //Script Assertion should fail.
    //TestStep should be marked red.
} else {
    log.info("OK! ResponseType is an image.")
}
```

Is there any way, how to let the script assertion fail depending on a property?
I've tried to use the *getStatus()* method, but this is only available for the testrunner object. Unfortunately the testRunner-object can not be used within a script assertion concerning this post: http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2494#p9107

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Need to assert so that test fails or passes automatically based on the condition.

```groovy
def httpResponseHeader = messageExchange.responseHeaders
def contentType = httpResponseHeader["Content-Type"]
log.info("Content-Type: " + contentType)
assert contentType.get(0) == "image/jpeg","Content Type is not an image"
```

EDIT: Earlier paid attention to how to throw error, assuming you have the rest in place. Now changed last line of code based on the input.

Comment: Well. You could also make the test fail in another way `if (contentType.get(0) != "image/jpeg") { throw new Error('Content Type is not an image')}`. But this is used in different context like, there are multiple checks you want to make without stopping on the first failure and in the end of the script make it failure. But assert stops at first failure, and does not look at the rest. So, use if conditions instead of asserts, then at the end throw error if any of the above ifs are failed. Hope this helps.